# binary xml file line #7 error inflating class Button

Tags: android, xml, button, android-fragments, runtime-error

I write a program with FrameLayout, when i clicked on the first button, the program show introduce.xml but when i clicked on the second button, the program Force Class. i think because i use Button in product.xml file because when i changed button to imageView, the program runs good. Why? How can solve this?

Runtime Error:

```
binary xml file line #7 error inflating class Button in android
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logoText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    android:text="@string/logotxt"/>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/b1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/btn1"
            />
    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/b2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn1"
            android:text="@string/btn2"
            />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/b3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn1"
            android:text="@string/btn3"
            />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/b4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn1"
            android:text="@string/btn4"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

product.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Buton
    android:id="@+id/android_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"

    android:text="@string/android"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public String fonts="BZar.ttf";

TextView logoText;
Button btnIntroduce;
Button btnProduct;
Button btnContact;
Button btnMore;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setFont();

    btnIntroduce.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    btnProduct.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn4:
            Log.e("button", "4click");
            //ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Introduce());
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new Introduce());
            ft.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            Log.e("button", "3Click");
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new Product());
            ft.commit();
            break;

        }
    }

};
```

Product.java:

```
    public class Product extends Fragment{

public String fonts="BZar.ttf";
Typeface face;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product, container, false);

    face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "font/"+fonts+"");

    /*Button btnAndroid=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.android_btn);
    btnAndroid.setTypeface(face);
    String android=(String)btnAndroid.getText().toString();
    btnAndroid.setText(PersianReshape.reshape(android));*/

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: its simple mistake you type Buton instead of Button in product.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a typo. `product.xml` only has 1 T in `Button`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali. I am confused :(

Comment: Occam's razor... the missing T was the answer to the question. The xml file was not expanding properly because `Buton` is not a valid view. What I would wonder is why your IDE didn't warn you.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I was having similar problems with View. It turns out that Android Studio creates lowercase "view" tag in .xml when creating CustomView in design mode.

Comment: If it's happening every time and you're on the latest build, [file a bug report](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs).